Selenium gets my cpu to 100% even after using driver.quit()
I am trying to crape data form a website using selenium and chromedriver and I need the tab to run at least 6 hours straight. I know the chrome driver creates many tabs at the same time like this:
Chromedriver tabs
and for the first few hours the driver.quit() method is able to close them all. But if I leave it running overnight, the CPU gets overloaded to 100% after about 5 or 6 hours(approximately) and open about 10-15 chrome tabs and cannot closing (I didn't take a screenshot because my PC was a a microwave at that point)
My code looking like this:
I am running it on local Jupyter notebook and Colab at the same time. The Jupyter notebook is overloaded after 5 hours of running and the Colab is still running after 12 hours but the process is slow
# setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--nogpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,1280")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

while page < len(listed):
  print(page)
  ua = UserAgent()
  userAgent = ua.random
  # set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
  chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
  # set the target URL
  url = 'https://batdongsan.com.vn' + listed[page]
  # set up the webdriver
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": userAgent})

  driver.get(url)

  # Wait for the page to load
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)

  # Get the page source
  html_data = driver.page_source

  # Parse the HTML data using BeautifulSoup
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

  # Close the web driver
  driver.quit()
  page += 1

Am I doing something wrong or just the selenium container take up a huge amount of cpu on its own? Is there any way to reduce the cpu usage of selenium or make sure all the tabs are closed after each session?

while page < len(listed): This is an infinite loop, because neither page nor listed ever change.

@JohnGordon I used while because I need to review some pages multiple times. But I can assure page does change and when I check the log before my PC crash it still changing

If so, then your real code must be different than you have posted here.

@JohnGordon I just left out the part where I'm getting the information I need and loop the pages necessary and as I said, the page still changing
